# Slice function for page navigation

Tags: php

I am trying to get a slice of an array for that corresponds to a page number. Every page contains 12 results. The output seems inconsistent. It functions as it should on the first page, but not on the others. I was wondering if someone can help me identify why this is and how to fix it?

```
echo count($results); // output: 227
echo $page; //output: 3
```

Get 12 results based on page number

```
//Page 1 = results 0-12
//Page 2 = results 12-24
//Page 3 = results 24-36 etc.

$results = array_slice($results, ($page-1)*12, $page*12); // array_slice($results, 24, 36)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it do on the subsequent pages?

Comment: Outputs more results than 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
$results = array_slice($results, ($page-1)*12, 12);
```

According to the php manual on [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), the second parameter is the offset (which you've got right).

The third parameter is the length of the slice.

12 is what you want, since you want 12 results per page.

Using `$page*12` for the third parameter gives you 12 results on the first page, 24 on the second, 36 on the third, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works great! I used slice like Javascript `.slice()` which works differently than the PHP `array_slice()`

Comment: No problem! Different languages have different perimeters for the same functions, docs are always helpful (: